# To show that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}\sin(bx)}{x}=\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

To show that

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}\sin(bx)}{x}$ = $\arctan \left( \frac{b}{a}\right)$

I have to use Frullani integral to do this. But i am not able to start.

Comment: Why down votes ?

Answer (score 3):

By Frullani:

$$-\frac1{2i}\log\frac{a+bi}{a-bi}=-\frac1{2i}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(a+ib)x}-e^{-(a-ib)x}}xdx=$$

$$=-\frac1{2i}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ax}(\cos bx-i\sin bx-\cos bx-i\sin bx)}xdx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ax}\sin bx}xdx$$

and now just check that

$$\frac1{2i}\log\frac{a-bi}{a+bi}=\frac1{2i}\log\frac{\frac ab-i}{\frac ab+i}=\arctan\frac ab-\frac\pi2=\arctan \frac ba$$

Comment: What is phi function in first integral

Comment: @TaylorTed Sorry but I don't understand your question: what phi in the first integral?

Comment: In other words how did you obtain first equation

Comment: Check here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html

Comment: What did you choose as  a $f$ to get first equation

Comment: The exponential $\;e^{-\alpha x}\;,\;\;\alpha\in\Bbb C\;$

Comment: @Joanpemo how to evaluate this equality $$\ln\frac{a-bi}{a+bi}=2i\arctan \frac ba .$$

Comment: @Achaire Together with explanation, very first page of http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf

Comment: @Joanpemo thank you :)